# OpenGL: Depth buffering working backwards, is it in the winding order?

Tags: python, opengl, matrix

I have been working on my opengl model viewer and have run into a problem. When I render my scene it seemed like the models were see through. I looked into it and thought maybe my depth buffer wasn't working but I had the code in place for it:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
```

and the test for the depth buffer

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_DEPTH_BITS)
```

returns a non 0 value (it returns 24). So I went deeper into testing it, and found that it wasn't that the depth buffer didn't work, it's that it works in reverse. It shows the back faces over the front ones. If I call glCullFace(GL_FRONT), the model's render normally. This is great but it poses an issue of why that happens, and I should probably get to the root of the problem. By looking around it seems like my winding order may be the issue, I built my own matrix stack for the modelviewprojectionmatrix and I think that may be the problem. If I render my scene with the camera moved backwards 20 units, with a horizontal fov of .785 rads, aspect of 1.333, clipplaneNear of 1.000, and clipplaneFar of 30.000 my matrices look like this:

```
model: 
[ 1 0 0 0 ]
[ 0 1 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 1 0 ]
[ 0 0 0 1 ]
view: 
[ 1   0   0   0 ]
[ 0   1   0   0 ]
[ 0   0   1   0 ]
[ 0   0   -20 1 ]
proj:  
[ 2.414214  0         0         0  ]
[ 0         -3.218951 0         0  ]
[ 0         0         -1.068966 -1 ]
[ 0         0         -2.068966 0  ]
```

When I have cullface on front this renders exactly how I want it to, with the object properly rendered 20 units away from the camera. I can spin it and move it like I want to and everything works. But without cullface the depth is reversed, is my z value messed up somewhere? Everything looks similar to the resources I've been working with so far. And if it's not that then where is this backwards problem coming from?

Comment: In the case where you have the problem, do you have `GL_CULL_FACE` enabled with `glCullFace(GL_BACK)`? Or do you have `GL_CULL_FACE` disabled?

Comment: If I leave it as GL_BACK the problem is there and if I disable it the problem remains the same. But the initial time I got the problem and the way I run it without the GL_FRONT is with it as GL_BACK

Answer (score 1):

I spent about 12 hours combing through all of my code and trying every possibility to find where I was going wrong. I narrowed it down to my projection matrix and then down to the second column second row. I used [this source](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/05/22/opengl-101-matrices-projection-view-model/) to read up on projection matrices and hand calculated it to find out what it should be with my values and then noticed a discrepancy. The value of 3.21 should be positive not negative and that was altering my depth value. I managed to find out that the library that I was using a port of was ported with an error. The library has a function for make_projection_fov that converted from field of view to top/bottom/right/left values and called a function make_projection. But the make_projection's parameters were right left top bottom near far and the make_projection_fov was calling it with right left bottom top near far. The negative was coming from there.

This taught me I really need to check over my libraries. I've since ran tests through all of my libraries functions and found another error in a few currently unused functions.

Comment: I had noticed that matrix element [1][1] is negative. That should have no influence on the depth, though. It just flips the y values upside down, and inverts the winding order in the process. This is why I asked what happens if you disable `GL_CULL_FACE`. If you had the problem with culling disabled, I don't think this alone explains it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this while using an orthographic projection as my perspective matrix. I fixed it by making sure that when defining `left`, `right`, `bottom`, `top`, `near` and `far` - `near` should be positive and `far` should be negative. Or at least `near` should be greater than `far`.

This seems to be because OpenGL interprets "forward" as -Z, so things further away in screen space should have smaller and smaller Z components.